# How to stop the autorefresh while the RadGrid is in Editmode

Tags: javascript, c#, timer, telerik

I have a Grid(parent Grid) and it has some rows. When i expand each row i have two tabs and clicking on each tab i am displaying other grids(child grids).

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Visible="false"
            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="False"
            AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="true" OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"
            OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">
            <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
            <MasterTableView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HierarchyDefaultExpanded="true" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True"
                GroupLoadMode="Server" EditMode ="Batch">
                <NestedViewTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="InnerContainer" CssClass="viewWrap" Visible="false">
                        <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="TabStip1" MultiPageID="Multipage1" SelectedIndex="0">
                            <Tabs>
                                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="First Grid" PageViewID="PageView1">
                                </telerik:RadTab>
                                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Second Grid" PageViewID="PageView2">
                                </telerik:RadTab>
                            </Tabs>
                        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                        <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="Multipage1" SelectedIndex="0" RenderSelectedPageOnly="false">
                            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="PageView1">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Font-Bold="true" Font-Italic="true" Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>'
                                    Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="OrdersGrid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ShowFooter="true"
                                    AllowSorting="true" EnableLinqExpressions="false">
                                    <MasterTableView ShowHeader="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true"
                                        DataKeyNames="OrderID" PageSize="7" HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand">
                                        <DetailTables>
                                            <telerik:GridTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="OrderID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
                                                Width="100%">
                                                <ParentTableRelation>
                                                    <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="OrderID" MasterKeyField="OrderID"></telerik:GridRelationFields>
                                                </ParentTableRelation>
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn SortExpression="ProductName" DataTextFormatString="Search Google for '{0}'"
                                                        DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductName" UniqueName="ProductName" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;q={0}&amp;btnG=Google+Search"
                                                        HeaderText="HyperLink Column" DataTextField="ProductName">
                                                    </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
                                                    <telerik:GridNumericColumn SortExpression="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                                        DataField="UnitPrice" DataFormatString="{0:C}" Aggregate="Avg" FooterAggregateFormatString="Average price: {0:C}">
                                                    </telerik:GridNumericColumn>
                                                    <telerik:GridNumericColumn SortExpression="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                                        DataField="Quantity" Aggregate="Max" FooterAggregateFormatString="Max quantity: {0}">
                                                    </telerik:GridNumericColumn>
                                                    <telerik:GridNumericColumn SortExpression="Discount" HeaderText="Discount" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                                        DataField="Discount" DataFormatString="{0:P}">
                                                    </telerik:GridNumericColumn>
                                                    <telerik:GridCalculatedColumn UniqueName="Total" DataFields="UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount"
                                                        Expression="IIf({2} = 0,{0}*{1}, {0}*{1}*{2})" HeaderText="Total" DataType="System.Double"
                                                        Aggregate="Sum" DataFormatString="{0:C}" FooterAggregateFormatString="Total cost: {0:C}">
                                                    </telerik:GridCalculatedColumn>
                                                </Columns>
                                                <SortExpressions>
                                                    <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="Quantity" SortOrder="Descending"></telerik:GridSortExpression>
                                                </SortExpressions>
                                            </telerik:GridTableView>
                                        </DetailTables>
                                        <Columns>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                                DataField="CompanyName" UniqueName="CompanyName">
                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn SortExpression="CompanyName" DataTextFormatString="Search Google for '{0}'"
                                                DataNavigateUrlFields="CompanyName" UniqueName="CompanyName" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;q={0}&amp;btnG=Google+Search"
                                                HeaderText="HyperLink Column" DataTextField="CompanyName">
                                            </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderID" HeaderText="OrderID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                                DataField="OrderID" UniqueName="OrderID" Aggregate="Count" FooterAggregateFormatString="Orders count: {0}">
                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn SortExpression="OrderDate" HeaderText="Order date" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                                DataField="OrderDate" UniqueName="OrderDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                                                Aggregate="Last" FooterAggregateFormatString="Last order dates: {0:d}">
                                            </telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Total" DataField="Total" HeaderText="Order Total"
                                                SortExpression="Total" DataFormatString="{0:C}">
                                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </MasterTableView>
                                    <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="true">
                                        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" ScrollHeight="" />
                                    </ClientSettings>
                                    <PagerStyle PageButtonCount="3" Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" ShowPagerText="false" />
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
                                    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.Freight, Customers.CompanyName, SUM(
                                    CASE WHEN [Order Details].Discount = 0     THEN 1 
                                    ELSE [Order Details].Discount END 
                                    * [Order Details].Quantity * [Order Details].UnitPrice) as Total     
                                    FROM (Orders LEFT JOIN Customers on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID) 
                                    FULL JOIN [Order Details] on Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID 
                                    Where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID 
                                    GROUP BY Orders.OrderID,Orders.OrderDate, Orders.Freight, Customers.CompanyName"
                                    runat="server">
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" Name="EmployeeID"></asp:ControlParameter>
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
                                    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT OrderID, [Order Details].UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount, Products.ProductName FROM ([Order Details] LEFT JOIN Products on [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID) where OrderID = @OrderID"
                                    runat="server">
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="OrderID" SessionField="OrderID" Type="Int32"></asp:SessionParameter>
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </telerik:RadPageView>
                            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="PageView">
                                <telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                                    AllowSorting="true">
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
                            </telerik:RadPageView>
                        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </NestedViewTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                        DataField="FirstName" UniqueName="FirstName">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                        DataField="LastName" UniqueName="LastName">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Title" HeaderText="Title" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                        DataField="Title" UniqueName="Title">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="BirthDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                        HeaderText="Birth Date" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="BirthDate" UniqueName="BirthDate">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="City" HeaderText="City" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                        DataField="City" UniqueName="City">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Country" HeaderText="Country" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                        DataField="Country" UniqueName="Country">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="true">
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" ScrollHeight="" />
            </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

I am implementing auto refreshing of the grids. For this purpose i have used the timer control and set an interval of 10 mins.

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="600000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>



protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ragdgrid1.rebind();
    radgrid2.rebind();
}
```

My problem here is when the grid is in edit mode(i am using batch editing) and the timer interval is reached it refreshes the grid and we lose the edit mode. So the user again need to enter the values for the grid.

How can I keep the grid in the edit mode when the timer interval is reached?